Can we define an absolute value on $\mathbb{Q}$ just not for primes?
Ostrowski's theorem tells us that any absolute value on $\mathbb{Q}$ is either the usual absolute value, $ |\cdot|_\infty $, or the $ p $-adic absolute value, $ |\cdot|_p $, for some prime $ p $. The $ p $-adic absolute value is given by
$$|x|_p = p^{-k}$$
where $ x = p^k \frac{a}{b} $ with $a$ and $ b $ coprime, and $ p $ does not divide $ a $ or $b$.
However, I'm wondering: why do we restrict $p$ to be prime? Can we define an absolute value using composite numbers?
Here's my idea. Let $n=pq$, where $ p $ and $ q $ are distinct primes. Given any $ x \in \mathbb{Q} $, we write $ x = p^t q^s \frac{a}{b} $ where $ (a,b) = 1 $, and neither $ p $ nor $ q $ divides $ a $ or $ b $. I define the following absolute value:
$$|x|_{pq} = \frac{1}{(pq)^{\min(t, s)}}.$$
This seems to satisfy the non-Archimedean property, since:
$$|x + y|_{pq} \leq \max\{|x|_{pq}, |y|_{pq}\}.$$
Here are my questions:

Will this define a valid (non-trivial) absolute value on $ \mathbb{Q} $?
If this is an absolute value, It must be equivalent to some prime $ p $-adic absolute value by Ostrowski's theorem, I wonder which prime.


looks like this won't be an absolute value, because it does not satisfy $|xy|{pq}=|x|{pq}|y|_{pq}$

but I still wonder, if we can define something like this for any natural number $n$ instead of just doing it for primes $p$

@Jakobian, it does not say that those are not absolute values, it says that any absolute value would be equivalent to either $| \cdot |_{\infty}$ or $| \cdot |_p$

In the wikipedia page for Ostrowski's theorem, two absolute values are equivalent implies they are powers of each other, so every absolute value on $\mathbb{Q}$ must be of the form $|\cdot|p^\lambda$ or $|\cdot|\infty^\lambda$ or $|\cdot|_0^\lambda$ for some $\lambda\in (0, \infty)$. I think it shouldn't be hard to see that $|\cdot |_n$ for $n$ not prime isn't of this form

true, but I was wondering where exactly we were using the fact that $p$ is a prime?

nitpick:  every non-trivial absolute value on $\mathbb Q$ is either  ...

Note if you don't think in terms of metrics and completions of $\mathbb Q$ but rather in terms of algebraic completions, you can use composite numbers and the result is just nothing so different as a product of the prime cases. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582002/why-are-p-adic-integers-more-interesting-than-for-instance-mathbbz-51/1582033. (The appearance of a product is related to the failure of your norm to be multiplicative.)

Your absolute value fails the multiplicative property. Say, $x=pq^3$ and $y=p^3q$; now what are $|x|,\;|y|$, and is it true that $|x|\cdot|y|=|xy|$? No.
Now one might wonder, what if we define $|x|_{pq} = \dfrac{1}{p^tq^s}$ instead of $\dfrac1{(pq)^{\min(t,s)}}$? Why, this restores multiplicativity, but breaks the triangle inequality. Say, $x=2^{10}$ and $y=3^{10}$; then $x+y$ is coprime to both $2$ and $3$, and its "norm" is way greater than $|x|+|y|$.
See, the theorem is there for a reason. There is no going around it.

This is a good exercise for any non-obvious theorem: Try leaving out one of the hypotheses, and see what happens.

Indeed, testing edge cases is an important skill in software development. Ditto for math.
